# Interleaving lines of two text files with arbitrary number of lines

Tags: linux, text-processing

I want to interleave lines of file A.txt with lines of file B.txt in a way that after every n lines of A.txt, m lines of B.txt shows up. As an examples, if A.txt is like:

```
1
2
3
4
```

and B.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
```

the desired output for n=2 and m=1 must be like:

```
1
2
a
3
4
b
```

In short, what I need is kind of "paste" utility's functionality with arbitrary "n" and "m" as options.

Comment: Actually thought of awk, but seems to require a lot of memory as my files are so large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say...

```
awk -v m=1 -v n=2 '
      FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next}
      1
      ++count==n {for (i=0;i<m;i++) print a[++t + i]; count=0}' fb fa
```

This stores all the `fileB` in an array on a way `a[number of line]=content`. Then, it keeps printing the `fileA` by adding lines in between taken from `a[]` on the following way:

- keep track in `count` of how many lines of `fileA` have been printed since the last print of lines from `fileB`. Once `count` matches the given `m`, start printing the next `n` lines from `fileB`.

#### Test

```
$ awk -v m=1 -v n=2 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} 1; ++count==n {for (i=0;i<m;i++) print a[++t + i]; count=0}' fb fa
1
2
a
3
4
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginnings of a `bash` solution - no error checking, especially for early end of file on one of the files; you'll have to decide how you want to handle that, since your question was a bit vague on that...

```
exec 3< fileA 4< fileB

while true
do
  for i in `seq M`
  do
    read -u 3 line
    echo "${line}"
  done

  for i in `seq N`
  do
    read -u 4 line
    echo "${line}"
  done
done

exec 3<&- 4<&-
```

This will at least avoid the need to load the entire files into memory at once. This concept could pretty easily be translated into Python or perl or one of several other scripting languages, where the error checking logic would be quite a bit easier to accomplish than in `bash`. Not so sure it would be done easily with `awk`, though...